# Twitter Polling feature

Tags: ios, twitter, polling

I did a bit of R&D for twitter integration in our application. Requirement is to create a twitter poll from my custom application.

As per my research there is no any SDK or twitter API available to do this. Still, wanted to confirm, it is possible? Am I missing something?

If anyone having knowledge regarding this, then kindly share with me.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You already know the answer. There's no API endpoint for polls.

Comment: @Moritz Thank you for your response! (Y)